# Записать и считать сложный объект класса из бинарника C++

Tags: c++, файлы, binary, binary-file

Есть несколько классов, они вложены друг в друга (в первом классе вектор вторых, в каждом втором вектор третьих) и имеют свои атрибуты. Пробовал делать запись и чтение так:

```
fout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&pr1), sizeof(pr1));//pr1 объект класса

in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&pr1_copy), sizeof(pr1_copy));
```

Проблема в том, что такая запись+чтение работает только вместе, мы записываем адреса из существующего объекта и если удалить pr1 перед считыванием из файла, то ничего в pr_copy не запишется, ведь за теми адресами будет мусор/пусто.
Следовательно вопрос: как сделать нормальную запись объекта в бинарный файл, чтобы можно было, к примеру, из другого проекта считать его?

Comment: QT не используете? Там сериализация несколько проще.

Comment: Еще можно посмотреть в сторону Protocol Buffers (protobuf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разрабатывать нетривиальную систему *сериализации*, которая аккуратно рассмотрит ваш объект как набор устойчивых кусочков и затем кусочек-за-кусочком запишет ваш объект в бинарный файл так, чтобы потом при чтении этих кусочков из файла можно было восстановить исходное состояние объекта. Разумеется, ни о какой записи "одним вызовом `write`" не может быть и речи, и ни о какой прямой записи указателей не может быть и речи тоже.

Comment: В C++ нет никаких библиотек для проделывания таких махинаций? Не представляю, как буду это писать..( вектора ведь могут быть разного размера, как это учитывать при считывании..

Comment: @Alex Как вариант, определить `template<class... Params> std::basic_ostream<Params...> &operator<<(std::basic_ostream<Params...> &, Class const &)`, внутри которого расписать всю маршализацию, предок за предком, поле за полем. Ну и `operator>>` соответственно.

Comment: Как вариант, обратиться к типу `ASN1` [синтаксису нотаций](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One)  при записи и чтении. Для этого типа есть готовые библиотеки сериализации.

Answer (score 0):

Ну давайте попробуем... Начнем изнутри. Пусть у нас есть, для простоты,

```
struct Inner
{
    vector<int> data;
};
```

Добавим к ней функции чтения и записи в файл. Главное - они должны быть согласованы и писать и читать один формат. Например, так:

```
struct Inner
{
    vector<int> data;

    ifstream& read(ifstream& in)
    {
        data.clear();
        size_t sz;
        in.read((char*)&sz,sizeof(sz));
        data.resize(sz);
        in.read((char*)&data[0],sizeof(sz));
    }

    ofstream& write(ofstream& out)
    {
        size_t sz = data.size();
        out.write((char*)&sz,sizeof(sz));
        out.write((char*)&data[0],sizeof(int)*sz);
        return out;
    }
};
```

И пусть у нас теперь есть

```
struct Outer
{
    vector<Inner> data;
};
```

Напишем точно такие же функции, только теперь при записи вектора будем писать элементы отдельно, по одному, не заботясь о том, как это делается - этим будут заниматься сами элементы:

```
struct Outer
{
    vector<Inner> data;

    ifstream& read(ifstream& in)
    {
        data.clear();
        size_t sz;
        in.read((char*)&sz,sizeof(sz));
        for(int i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
        {
            Inner iobj;
            iobj.read(in);
            data.push_back(iobj);
        }
        return in;
    }

    ofstream& write(ofstream& out)
    {
        size_t sz = data.size();
        out.write((char*)&sz,sizeof(sz));
        for(int i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
        {
            Inner& iobj = data[i];
            iobj.write(out);
        }
        return out;
    }

};
```

Представим, что у нас есть еще и поле `char*`, указатель на строку. Допишем и его запись-чтение:

```
struct Outer
{
    vector<Inner> data;
    char * s;

    ifstream& read(ifstream& in)
    {
        data.clear();
        size_t sz;
        in.read((char*)&sz,sizeof(sz));
        for(int i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
        {
            Inner iobj;
            iobj.read(in);
            data.push_back(iobj);
        }

        in.read((char*)&sz,sizeof(sz));
        delete[] s;
        s = new char[sz];
        in.read(s,sz);


        return in;
    }

    ofstream& write(ofstream& out)
    {
        size_t sz = data.size();
        out.write((char*)&sz,sizeof(sz));
        for(int i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
        {
            Inner& iobj = data[i];
            iobj.write(out);
        }

        sz = strlen(s)+1;
        out.write((char*)&sz,sizeof(sz));
        out.write(s,sz);


        return out;
    }

};
```

И так - для всех полей, причем если поля сложные - свои классы, то лучше им самим заниматься собой...

Написать чтение-запись для

```
struct Envelope
{
    vector<Outer> data;
};
```

сами теперь сможете? :)