# С++ запись в файл контейнер list

Tags: c++

Есть класс с полями:

```
class User {
private:
    char idUser[10];
    char surName[20];
    char name[20];
    char middleName[20];
    char gender[1];
    int countAdult;
    int countChildren;
    list <int> idTours;
    bool vip = false;
    int spentMoney = 0;
    int buyTours = 0 ;
public:
    ...
};
```

1. Ввод данных -> запись в файл. **Всё работает**
2. Когда пытаюсь считать данные с файла и сохранить в вектор, появляется ошибка (**System.AccessViolationException**)

Ф-я считывания с файла:

```
VectorUser loadFromFile()
{
    ifstream Fin;
    Fin.open("E:\\users.dat", ios::binary);

    VectorUser temp;

    if (!Fin.is_open())
        return temp;

    User user;

    while (!Fin.eof())
    {
        if (Fin.read((char*)&temp, sizeof(User)))           
            temp.AddUser(user);
    }

    Fin.close();
    return temp;
}
```

Предполагаю, что ошибка возникает из-за попытки записать данные в list. Как это исправить?

Comment: Да ничего при записи не работает... Вы записываете какие-то адреса, а не реальные данные. Писать список надо по одному элементу, а потом при чтении читать их по одному и вставлять в пустой список... Т.е. у вас получается достаточно сложная функция записи в файл и чтения из него. Написать-то ее можно, но не проще ли держать не список (на каждый `int` — еще два указателя... зачем?), а массив `int`'ов? Вряд ли у вас там нужен ну очень большой массив...

Comment: Используется list, потому что в него будут постоянно добавляться данные и сколько их будет неизвестно.

Comment: Тогда пишите функцию сохранения списка (хотя для того же вектора она существенно проще). Посмотрите тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/919910/195342